Mocking Neo4J GraphQL OGM in typescript / vitetest
I'm struggling to get a clean solution to mock the use of Noe4j GraphQL OGM using vitetest but cant quite work out the best way to do this cleanly..
I do not seem to be able to find a way to mock either the OGM generated <type>Model class, or the OGM.prototype.model function which is used to get the generated <type>Model using vanilla vitest.
I managed to solve this using vitest-mock-extended, but I feel/worry that this is a case where either I am missing some obvious way to do this with vanilla vitest, or, its a sign that I should be isolating the OGM parts and injecting more easily testable interface.
My questions are:

Has anyone mocked OGM and is there an approach to mocking ogm.model using vanilla vitest (or equivalent framework) that I am missing?
for mocking the generated Model classes (ie UserModel), again, is there an approach using vanilla vitest I am missing?
have/would people recommend an alternative approach to create a wrapper/interface that is more easily testable / better suited for mocking and pass that into a version of UserSignup, and then have a UserSignupWithOGM(...) that takes OGM and does the ogm.model call passing in UserModel into the UserSignup (while I cant change the generated code, I'm happy isolating the rest of the codebase from this)

A simplified version of the setup is that I have a UserSignup that leverages a generated GraphQL function that OGM provides.  so I have (simplified)
// UserSignup.ts

// UserSignup is registered as a resolver on the graphql server (apollo)
export const UserSignup =  async (
   _source: unknown, 
   { username, password }: { username: string, password: string }, 
   // ogm is passed in via context by the server
   { ogm } : { ogm: OGM<ModelMap> }) => {
  // ogm provides a typesafe way to get the class we can then use to exercise the graphQL API
  const User = ogm.model("User")
  const [existing] = await User.find({
      where: {
          username,
      },
  });
  if (existing) {
      throw new Error(`User with username ${username} already exists!`);
  }
  const { users } = await User.create({
      input: [
          {
              username,
              password,
          }
      ]
  });

  // assume a bunch more here ...

  return users[0].id;
}

In my test, I cannot seem to find a way to get a mocked version of ogm so that ogm.model("User") would give a mocked version of the UserModel
And given OGM is generating the code, cant change any types etc..
I also could not get vanilla vitest to give a mock on the UserModel class.
the best I have found so far is to use vitest-mock-extended (see below)
// UserSignup.test.ts
import { expect, test } from "vitest";
import { UserSignup } from "../UserSignup";
import { OGM } from "@neo4j/graphql-ogm";
import { UserModel, ModelMap } from "../../generated/ogm-types";
import { mockDeep, mock } from "vitest-mock-extended";

const UserModelMock = mock<UserModel>();

const ogm = mockDeep<OGM<ModelMap>>({ funcPropSupport: true });
ogm.model.calledWith("User").mockReturnValue(UserModelMock);

test("Test User Signup", async () => {
   UserModelMock.find
      .calledWith(any())
      .mockReturnValue(Promise.resolve([]);

   UserModelMock.create
      .calledWith(any())
      .mockReturnValue(Promise.resolve([ { username: 'test', password: '', id: 'new_user' }]));
   const userId = await UserSignup();
   expect(userId).toBe('new_user');
});


Here is the definition of OGM:
// @neo4j/graphql-ogm.d.ts
declare class OGM<ModelMap = unknown> {

   constructor(input: OGMConstructor);
    // etc
   model<M extends T extends keyof ModelMap ? ModelMap[T] : Model, T extends keyof ModelMap | string = string>(name: T): M;
   // etc
}

and UserModel:
// ../../generated/ogm-types.ts

export declare class UserModel {
  public find(args?: {
    where?: UserWhere;

    options?: UserOptions;
    selectionSet?: string | DocumentNode | SelectionSetNode;
    args?: any;
    context?: any;
    rootValue?: any;
  }): Promise<User[]>;
  public create(args: {
    input: UserInput[];
    selectionSet?: string | DocumentNode | SelectionSetNode;
    args?: any;
    context?: any;
    rootValue?: any;
  }): Promise<UsersMutationResponse>;
  public update(args: {
    where?: UserWhere;
    update?: UserUpdateInput;
    connect?: UserConnectInput;
    disconnect?: UserDisconnectInput;
    create?: UserCreateInput;
    connectOrCreate?: UserConnectOrCreateInput;
    selectionSet?: string | DocumentNode | SelectionSetNode;
    args?: any;
    context?: any;
    rootValue?: any;
  }): Promise<UpdateUsersMutationResponse>;
  public delete(args: {
    where?: UserWhere;
    delete?: UserDeleteInput;
    context?: any;
    rootValue?: any;
  }): Promise<{ nodesDeleted: number; relationshipsDeleted: number }>;
  public aggregate(args: {
    where?: UserWhere;

    aggregate: UserAggregateSelectionInput;
    context?: any;
    rootValue?: any;
  }): Promise<UserAggregateSelection>;
}

